# Extending two java classes without composition

Tags: java, inheritance, extend

I have two configuration classes: `MainConfiguration` and `Configuration` each with several fields.

```java
class MainConfiguration {
    public String a;
    public String b;
    public String c;
    // ...
}
```

```java
class Configuration {
    public String d;
    public String e;
    public String f;
    // ...
}
```

The goal is to be able to use `MainConfiguration`, and `MainConfiguration + Configuration` as two independent classes. Assume that I also cannot:

- Use composition / dependency injection
- Make changes to the Configuration class

For example, I could do

```java
class NewConfiguration extends Configuration {
    // copy fields from MainConfiguration
    public String a;
    public String b;
    public String c;
    // ...
}
```

but that would replicate fields from `MainConfiguration`. What would be the cleanest way to achieve this goal?

Comment: What is the reason of avoiding composition for your case?

Comment: The configuration class extends to an application framework that expect the contents to be  available at the first level of the class. For example, new Class.getD() not new Class.configuration().getD()

Comment: No problem if your framework relies on get-methods: declare two fields per each type of configuration, and declare six get methods to take fields from their respective backing fields.

Comment: I've give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out the fields are serialized / deserialized using @JsonProperty annotations within the class, making composition not possible.

Comment: Did you try putting the `@JsonProperty` annotation for your methods, not for the fields?